# Use HasTraits and PyQt signals in one class

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, traits

I have a huge traits application, which is running into the limitations of enthought traits. Mainly performance issues when using the @on_traits_changed decorator. It would be pretty straightforward to circumvent those issues with PyQt4 (or PyQt5) signals, if i could do:

```
from traits.api import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Foo(HasTraits, QtCore.QObject):
    pass
```

Error stack:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ecdfa57492f7> in <module>()
      2 from PyQt4 import QtCore
      3
----> 4 class Foo(HasTraits, QtCore.QObject):
      5     pass

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.pyc in __new__(cls, class_name,
bases, class_dict)
    427
    428         # Finish building the class using the updated class dictionary:
--> 429         klass = type.__new__( cls, class_name, bases, class_dict )
    430
    431         # Fix up all self referential traits to refer to this class:

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict)
subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

But from all i know that is not possible. Is there some workaround?

EDIT: added imports

EDIT2: added error stack

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible? What testing have you done?

Comment: I tested the code I posted and it throws an error. I did not find any solution to that problem, so I am asking here now.

Comment: @HeinzKurt. Why do you need to use multiple inheritance? Why don't you just create an internal instance of `QObject` and delegate to that? Also, have you tested using the latest version of PyQt5?

Comment: I did not know about delegation, and i can not try it out today. But from what i quickly read about it, this could be the solution to my problem. If it is, i will let you know.

Comment: class foo(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self) :pass


class off(HasTraits):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(foo,self).__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

Comment: How do you expect Qt signals/slots to resolve a performance issue?  Don't signals/slots necessarily introduce additional complexity and overhead that wasn't there before?

Comment: @Paul Cornelius: Performance of the on_trait_change decorator coming with HasTraits is extremely lousy, in particular when it comes to memory usage. Signals coming with PyQt will be much better.

Comment: @SDilmac: Thank you for the suggestion, but the final error message is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggested solution is to forget about Qt.  Anything you can do with custom Qt Signals and Slots you can do with pure Python.  Here is an example of a class, PSignal, that has exactly the same public interface as Signal in Qt.  Instances of PSignal can be added to any Python object without the necessity of subclassing QObject, or even without using the Qt library at all.  Unlike Qt Signals they can be instantiated as instance variables inside the `__init__` method of any class, rather than at class level (as Qt requires).  Also, `emit` is a standard Python method and takes any number of arguments and keywords, thus making the whole mechanism more 'Pythonic'. The only thing lacking here is the thread-switching behavior of Signals and Slots, which does not seem to be a requirement here.

By overriding methods `emit` and `_emit` in subclasses you can adapt this simple gadget to a variety of situations, something you can't do easily with Qt Signals.

```
DEBUG = False

class PSignal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__handlers = [] 

    def connect(self,f):
        """f is a python function."""
        if not callable(f):
            raise ValueError("Object {!r} is not callable".format(f))
        self.__handlers.append(f)
        if DEBUG:
            print("Connecting",f,self.__handlers)

    def disconnect(self,f):
        for f1 in self.__handlers:
            if f == f1:
                self.__handlers.remove(f)
                return

    def emit(self,*x,**y):
        self._emit(*x,**y)

    def _emit(self,*x,**y):
        for f in self.__handlers:
            try:
                if DEBUG:
                    print("emit",f,len(x),x,y)
                f(*x,**y)
            except Exception:
                print("Error in signal",f)
                traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Very neat piece of code! Unfortunately sharing one instance of PSignal between all instances of my application in my special case adds too much complexity.

Comment: Thanks, but the intention of PSignal is not to "share" among other objects, but to use it exactly like a Qt Signal: you attach clients to it by calling connect(), exactly like a Signal.  It has the same API as Signal and is virtually a drop-in replacement, so I can't see how any application that uses Signals cannot use PSignals, which are after all more lightweight.  You can mix and match freely PSignals and Signals, migrating from one to the other as desired.  I've been using it for months and replaced Signal with PSignal in many places, and never had a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Although your answer strictly speaking does not answer my question, it still is a very nice workaround, so I accepted it anyway.